# Does Chrome NaCl have anything to do with V8?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8, google-nativeclient

Does one enable the other, or does one affect the other?

It seems V8 lets native C++ access Javascript, and NaCl lets you run native code in the browser.

Sorry for the naive question. I'm behind on recent developments in Javascript, was surprised that modern browsers actually JIT-compile all!

Answer (score 2):

Short answer- No.

Longer answer,

Chrome ships with the V8 JS engine and uses it to execute JavaScript embedded in web pages. V8 in Chrome cannot be extended to access C++ or vice versa.

NaCl is a toolchain and runtime environment allowing you to compile your existing C++ code into a safe executable and then execute it securely from a web page.

V8 can be used on its own by embedding it inside your own C++ application, extending it as you see fit.

HTH,
John

Answer (score 1):

http://research.google.com/pubs/archive/37204.pdf

It is possible to run (a modified version of) v8 inside NaCl. The code sequences emitted by the JIT must conform to the sandbox safety rules.

It is unlikely to be possible to do the converse.

:-)

-bsy